# Proprietary Nvidia drivers 367.35 cannot be found in Additional Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, proprietary

I cannot change my GPU driver open source to proprietary that I installed from ppa `add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`. I installed driver 367.35. It shows in the terminal that I installed it:

```
nvidia-smi
Thu Aug  4 13:06:37 2016       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.35                 Driver Version: 367.35                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 820M        Off  | 0000:04:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    106MiB /  1984MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I resolve this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. Try to use command line or synaptic.

For command line search for drivers with

```
apt-cache search nvidia
```

And install nvidia driver

```
sudo apt install nvidia-VERSION
```

nvidia-VERSION is meant nvidia package with version, for example nvidia-367, nvidia-352 etc. This will not show you nvidia drivers in Additional drivers, it is only an alternate method for installing nvidia drivers.

Found this [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html)

Comment: Unable to locate. I can't find it also

Comment: You have opened terminal and command apt-cache search nvidia does not find anything or there is other problem ?

Comment: the problem is <code> E: Unable to locate package nvidia-VERSION</code> after I typed sudo apt-get install nvidia-VERSION. and I search in <code> apt-cache search nvidia </code> and there isno nvidia-VERSION</code>

Comment: nvidia-VERSION is meant nvidia package with version, for example nvidia-367, nvidia-352 etc. This will not show you nvidia drivers in Additional drivers, it is only an alternate method for installing nvidia drivers.

Comment: But I can't also use the proprietary driver and I sense that it uses open source driver instead.

Comment: You are using proprietary driver, command `nvidia-smi` shows that. Status in Additional drivers is missleading. You can check if open source noveau drivers is loaded with command `lsmod | grep nouveau`. If it returns empty output it means you are using binary driver. With command `lsmod | grep nvidia` you can check if binary driver is loaded.

Comment: What is binary driver of proprietary or open source? There is no output when I try <code> lsmod | grep </code> but when I try lsmod | grep this is the result:
nvidia_uvm            659456  0
nvidia_drm             45056  1
nvidia_modeset        765952  4 nvidia_drm
nvidia              11247616  68 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
drm_kms_helper        147456  2 i915,nvidia_drm
drm                   364544  8 i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm

Comment: Binary driver `nvidia` is provided by nvidia company and it is closed source - only nvidia can change source code. `nouveau ` is open source driver which is source code is publicly avaliable and it is maintained by open source community. You are using nvidia driver.